# Get specific elements of a list using a list iteration

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, iteration

I'm trying to build the below dataframe

```py
df  = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Year','Revenue','Gross Profit','Operating Profit','Net Profit']) 
rep_vals =['year','net_sales','gross_income','operating_income','profit_to_equity_holders']

 for i in range (len(yearly_reports)): 
    df.loc[i] = [yearly_reports[i].x for x in rep_vals]
```

However I get error as per.. ***'Report' object has no attribute 'x'***

The below (brute force version) of the code works:

```py
for i in range (len(yearly_reports)): 
    df.loc[i] = [yearly_reports[i].year,yearly_reports[i].net_sales ,
                 yearly_reports[i].gross_income, yearly_reports[i].operating_income, 
                 yearly_reports[i].profit_to_equity_holders]
```

My issue is however I want to add a lot more columns and also I don't want to fetch every item from my yearly_reports into the dataframe, how can I iterate the values I want more effeciently please?

Comment: `getattr(yearly_reports[i], x)`?

Comment: what is `yearly_reports` ?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), currently, your code is not runnable because we are missing needed variables to understand what's going on.

Comment: @Umar.H - its a list containing a bespoke class called reports, fetched via an API, containing some data relating to financial statements.

Comment: @BeRT2me - The problem is yearly reports is a bespoke object/class from a paid API, so I don't know how I would make yearly reports reproducable, but luckily Lecdi's solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.x`, use `[x]`.

`yearly_reports[i][x]`

Also, it is probably a bad idea / not necessary / slow to iterate over your dataframe like this. Have a look at join/merge which might be a lot faster.